# C# Get Permanent Authentication Token Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets

I have a C# program that will add data to a Google Sheets spreadsheet. It authenticates with OAuth 2.0. I have it working with a single time code. However, in the samples Google provides they say:

> Once the user authorizes with Google, the request token can be exchanged  for a long-lived access token.

Does anyone know how to get this *long-lived access token*?

Comment: Have a look at [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

Comment: @abraham How would I implement this in a C# application?